# How to use InternetGetLastResponseInfo in C

Tags: c, winapi

I have big problems using the `InternetGetLastResponseInfo` function because of all the weird file types.

Can anyone give me some short example code showing how to use it and printing the Error afterwards (in C)?

Edit: Found it out now

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383884(v=vs.85).aspx) is example, but what have you tried. Add code and errors description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works now. Code:

```
DWORD error = GetLastError();
printf("Error: %d\n", error);
DWORD dwInetError;
DWORD dwExtLength = 1000;
TCHAR *szExtErrMsg = NULL;
TCHAR errmsg[1000];
szExtErrMsg = errmsg;
int returned = InternetGetLastResponseInfo( &dwInetError, szExtErrMsg, &dwExtLength );
printf("dwInetError: %d  Returned: %d\n", dwInetError, returned);
_tprintf(_T("Buffer: %s\n"), szExtErrMsg);
```